# Quite pythonic but not convincing as pandas style

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe where each series if filled with 0 and 1 as follows:

```
flagdf=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1], 'b':[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]})
```

Now, depending on some analysis I have done, I need to change some 0s to 1s. So the final dataframe will be:

```
final=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1], 'b':[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]})
```

The results of the analysis which shows which 0s have to be changed are stored in a second dataframe built with a multi-index:

```
     first  last
a 1      1     1
  5      5     6
b 0      0     1
  5      5     5
  7      7     7
```

For each 'a' and 'b' I have the first and the last indexes of the 0s I need to change.

First question: The second index in the multi-index dataframe is equal to the series 'first'. I was initially trying to use it directly, but I found it easier to handle two series rather than an index and a series. Am I missing something?

Here is the code to do the job:

```
def change_one_value_one_column(flagdf,col_name,event):
    flagdf[col_name].iloc[event]=1

def change_val_column(col_name, tochange, flagdf):
    col_tochange=tochange.ix[col_name]
    tomod=col_tochange[['first','last']].values
    iter_tomod=[xrange(el[0],el[1]+1) for el in tomod]
    [change_one_value_one_column(flagdf,col_name,event) for iterel in iter_tomod for event in iterel]

[change_val_colmun(col_name) for col_name in flagdf.columns]
```

Second question: I genuinely think that a list comprehension is always good but in cases like that, when I write a function specifically for a list comprehension, I have some doubt. Is it truly the best thing to do?

Third question: I think that the code is quite pythonic, but I am not proud of that because of the last list comprehension which is running over the series of the dataframe: using the method apply would look better to my eyes (but I'm not sure how to do it). Nontheless is there any real reason (apart from elegance) I should work to do the changes?

Comment: just a heads up, list comprehensions are bad to use for side effects as they needlessly create lists that you never use.

Comment: ...which is exactly what happens here. map would be better? ...But its use is deprecated...

Comment: Ah I see this is an example of partitioning groupby, much easier to see when you give the changed (difference) dataframe.

Comment: Can you give an example of tochange or an example of calling the function? Thanks.

Comment: You already have tochange. Is the third DataFrame introduced in the question.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the part about exhausting an iterator, I think you have a few pythonic choices (all of which I prefer over a list comprehension):

```
# the easiest, and most readable
for col_name in flagdf.columns:
    change_val_column(col_name)

# consume/exhaust an iterator using built-in any (assuming each call returns None)
any(change_val_colmun(col_name) for col_name in flagdf.columns)

# use itertools' consume recipe
consume(change_val_colmun(col_name) for col_name in flagdf.columns)
```

*See [consume recipe from itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).*

However, when doing this kind of thing in numpy/pandas, you should be asking yourself "can I vertorize / use indexing here?". If you can your code will usually be both faster and more readable.

I *think* in this case you'll be able to remove one level of loops by doing something like:

```
def change_val_column(col_name, tochange, flagdf):
    col_tochange = tochange.ix[col_name]  # Note: you're accessing index not column here??
    tomod = col_tochange[['first','last']].values
    for i, j in tomod:
        flag_df.loc[i:j, col_name] = 1
```

You **may** even be able to remove the for loop, but it's not obvious how / what the intention is here...

Comment: Now I think about it, I'd probably do some reshaping of `changed = final - flagdf; first = (changed != changed.shift(1).fillna(0)) & (changed == 1); last = (changed != changed.shift(-1).fillna(0)) & (changed == 1)` Not sure exactly what you end game is.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm staying in python and iterating over rows, I prefer using `zip`/`izip` as a first pass.

```
for col, start, end in izip(to_change.index.get_level_values(0), tochange['first'], tochange['last']):
     flagdf.loc[start:end, col] = 1
```

Simple and fast.